# Eclipse: quickly create method template from definition in interface

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I use Eclipse sometimes and when I type a name of a method that doesn't exist I can create this method's new body via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> menu. Is there some shortcut that allows to make same thing with new methods in an interface? I know that there are some shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> allowing to do that if you are in the implementing class. But I want to do that standing on a newly defined method in the interface. Is that possible in standard Java EE Eclipse bundle?

Comment: You want to create method in all classes that implement this interface by selecting method in interface and using some shortcut, right?

Comment: @AleksandrM I wouldn't mind if IDE asked me which class I want it to be implemented in. But the way you describe it will also suite me.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such feature out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Eclipse for years and years, and I feel fairly confident to say that the feature you are searching for is **not supported**.

So, unless you want to write your own plugin, I will supply the way I usually (quite quickly if you don't have tons of implementations) perform this action:

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> with the marker over the interface to bring up the type hierarchy:

[image: Type hierarchy view]

It lists all known implementations and lets you easily select the one you want to add the stub to. Selecting that class automatically puts the marker on the implementation. Then just do a quick <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and select *Add unimplemented methods*.

Although the functionality you are looking for sounds neat, this works good enough for me, and I don't think you can do better than this with vanilla Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed description. I find irritating that I actually have to move cursor out of my new method's declaration before I press Ctrl+t. Otherwise Eclipse will try to lookup the method's implementation, will fail and show me the interface only. Well, I'm just too spoiled with Jetbrains' products. I guess I will have to suffer on this project( using Eclipse is the requirement from the customer).

Comment: I see your problem. Would be fun to write a plugin that supports this. Btw, IDEA totally outshines Eclipse in many areas.